# Linux usb device forwarding

Tags: linux

I have a Linux (Ubuntu Server) box with a device (Panasonic PBX) connected to it via USB. On my host I have Linux (Ubuntu, desktop).

Can I transparently forward that USB device from Server to Desktop in order to maintain it locally?

---

That software does not work under Linux, so locally I have a VirtualBoxed Windows with PBX Maintenance software. I'd like VirtualBox to think that PBX is connected locally :)

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [USB/IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/): it does not encrypt the traffic (don't expose sensitive data/devices to the internet!) but works like a charm.

Here's a [usb/ip tutorial](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-modify-your-gnu-linux-box-to-serve-as-a-usb-over-ip-server) on how to set it up